# Long delays on TGV trip to Paris. Compensation from SNCF is less than expected. Should I appeal?

Tags: delays, compensation, sncf

I had a lousy weekend trip from Stuttgart to Paris back in February. The train was initially delayed and then cancelled. An official told us to take the train to Mannheim and then to Paris. We arrived in Paris over 3 hours late. The return train was over 1 hour late arriving.

I submitted a claim on that basis. My estimate was that I should get <strike>75%</strike> 50% for the outward journey and 25% for the return.

I received an email today saying that they would pay 50% for the outward journey and nothing for the return.

Is my estimate correct and it is worth appealing?

*Update*

The tickets were bought online at SNCF.

SNCF compensation policy is
[sncf.com/fr/service-client/en-cas-de-retard/tgv-intercites](http://sncf.com/fr/service-client/en-cas-de-retard/tgv-intercites)

Comment: On what basis did you come to your "estimates"?

Answer (score 3):

The compensation of 25% for 1 hour delay and 50% for 2 hours delay do not accumulate in case of longer delays. So 50% for the outward journey is correct. However, if you arrived more than 1 hour late at your destination on your return, you should be eligible for a 25% refund for that part as well (keep in mind, that the delay at your destination counts, not the delay of a single train leg in your journey).

Edit: Above numbers are related to the European rules for delay compensations. However, SNCF offers a more detailed compensation scheme for TGV tickets. However, the information about that seem to be a bit contradicting between the different translations on the SNCF homepage.
Following links indicate, that the G30 guarantee, which would offer 75% compensation for delays over 3 hours, is also valid for international tickets:
https://www.sncf.com/fr/service-client/en-cas-de-retard/tgv-intercites
https://en.oui.sncf/en/help-en/delay-train

According to the following link though, it seems to only apply to domestic TGV routes, while for international routes the compensation is similar to the EG rules:
https://www.oui.sncf/aide/retard-de-votre-train-et-remboursement

Comment: the outbound leg was over 3hrs. Compensation for the return leg was ignored completely by SNCF

Comment: Then the source of 75% is wrong. What's also important is, where you bought the ticket. Did you buy it directly from SNCF or from DB?

Comment: yes you're right. I misread the 75%. I bought the tickets online with SNCF.

Comment: Ah, in that case you may be right about the 75%, because SNCF grants more compensation than the EG rule mandates. According to https://www.sncf.com/fr/service-client/en-cas-de-retard/tgv-intercites for delays above 3 hours you should get 75% refund. What was the scheduled and the actual arrival in Paris?

Comment: :-) thought I'd seen it somewhere. Just not sure if it applies because I took a different route (on the advice of DB personnel)

Comment: As long as you used still TGV trains, the G30 guarantee should apply. If you used an ICE as replacement, then it doesn't apply and the EG rule would apply, which grants 50% for over 2 hours.

Comment: Here https://www.oui.sncf/aide/retard-de-votre-train-et-remboursement there's a dedicated part for international journeys that mentions a maximum of 50 % if more than 2 hours delay at arrival.

Comment: Concerning the return leg, maybe it's the DB that must deal with your delay ?

Comment: Regarding the return, at least according to the EG rules, the ticket issuer is the one which deals with compensations. And regarding SNCF, the 75% for international trips are mentioned here: https://en.oui.sncf/en/help-en/delay-train

Comment: So it seems, that the english pages are outdated and you should only refer to the french pages, when it comes to such information.

Comment: @dunni Ok that seems to explain the situation. The trip Stuttgart - Mannheim was with an ICE. The whole trip was international. Guess I'll take the 50% offer. Thanks everyone

Comment: @paul don't forget to accept this answer, if you're happy with it.